# How do I make an POST request inside of Twilio functions?

Tags: node.js, twilio

I'm trying to get a post request working inside of Twilio Functions, with my example below it never runs the fetch. The only time that it tries running something is when I add a console.log() outside of fetch, but it still does run fetch. I am trying to get it to fetch a local server (why I'm using ngrok) using ngrok, once it worked I was gonna host it but I can't even get around this issue.

Thanks in advance!

```js
// This is your new function. To start, set the name and path on the left.

exports.handler = function (context, event, callback) {
    // Here's an example of setting up some TWiML to respond to with this function
    let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse();
    
    var data = {}
    data.message = event.Body
    
    var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }
    
    const fetch = require('node-fetch');
    
    var url = 'https://b823c88c06c9.ngrok.io'
    
    fetch(url, options)
    .then(function(res) {
        return res.json();
    }).then(function(json) {
        console.log(json);
        console.log('mes')
    });
    

    return callback(null, twiml);
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Follow these examples:

[Make a Write Request to an External API using JSON](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/quickstart/serverless-functions-make-a-write-request-to-an-external-api-json)

[Make a Write Request to an External API using urlencoded data](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/quickstart/serverless-functions-make-a-write-request-to-an-external-api-urlencoded)

In you examples, the `return callback(null, twiml);` needs to be nested in the promise, reference [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions/invocation#callback-and-asynchronous-limitations).